# "Safari wants to use your confidential information stored in "website" in your keychain"

Tags: macos, safari, google-chrome, keychain

I had to install Google Chrome on my Mac for some reason, but do not intend to use it as my default browser. After logging in with my Google account, the following happened:

1. All my saved passwords on Chrome now appear in Safari saved passwords. I have no idea how this has been done.
2. Each time I visit a website in Safari, there's a popup saying "Safari wants to use your confidential information stored in "website" in your keychain".

For the 1st problem, ok it's fine, although it should have asked for my approval before importing the passwords. The 2nd is really annoying. Please suggest me a way to get rid of those popups (without disabling Keychain of course).

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

> Open Keychain Access.app in your Utilities folder. Highlight one of
>   familiar keychain entries on the right side or type a familiar name in
>   the spotlight panel.
>
> Then double click the entry. When the panel opens, select "Access
>   Control".
>
> In the "Always allow access" panel, click on the +, then navigate to
>   Safari in your Applications folder. Save changes.
>
> Just for good measure, go to the Keychains Menu>Keychain First-Aid and
>   select "repair". If any errors appear, rerun until you get a clean
>   pass.
>
> Close Keychain Access and restart Safari.

source:https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2060870?tstart=0

Comment: Thanks. As I understand, I have to allow access to each website for Safari? Is that the only solution? Can we remove all the stuffs imported from Chrome?

Comment: It is not per web site, it is global for Safari Find Safari in key chain and allow access.. What about Chrome ? yes you can remove the imported stuff, it will be still in Chrome.

Comment: "Highlight one of familiar keychain entries...". Actually a keychain entry is created for each login account, thus if we choose an entry and modify it, then this does not has any effect on the other entries (i.e. other login accounts of the same website or of other websites).

Comment: Works. Should be marked as correct answer.