# Strange Keychain Popups in Safari

Tags: macos, security, keychain

I just upgraded my Mac from El Capitan to Sierra, and now I'm getting some weird keychain popups in Safari.

When I browse Safari, if I visit a site for which I have credentials stored, a dialog pops up asking me whether or not to allow Safari to use the keychain info for an entirely different URL than the one I'm currently visiting (the url is a development server of mine). Here's a screenshot of it happening on Stack Overflow:

[image: Keychain popup]

*Translation by @owlswipe:* `Safari wants to access confidential information stored in [website] in your keychain` with buttons for <kbd>Always Allow</kbd>, <kbd>Allow</kbd>, and <kbd>Deny</kbd>.

Then it gets weirder: when I click "allow", a second prompt appears, requesting an administrator's password and mentioning [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/), a system settings extension for advanced mouse settings that I've installed.

[image: Keychain popup 2]

*Translation by @owlswipe:* `For security reasons, please enter an administrator's password to confirm the action. You can add "SteerMouse Manager" to the list of input helpers in System Preferences to stop displaying this password dialog.` with a username and password field and buttons for <kbd>Cancel</kbd> and <kbd>OK</kbd>.

I don't have any reason to think that SteerMouse is trying to do anything nefarious here, as it's a widely recommended, popular product. But all this seems a little weird.

I know I can probably make it shut up by doing what the dialog says, but before I do so, can anyone explain what is going on here?

Comment: This is a duplicate of [this question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163525/safari-wants-to-use-your-confidential-information-stored-in-website-in-your-k), I would close it if it didn't have a bounty.

Comment: What you're talking about is also answered [here](http://www.hawkdive.com/2016/03/safari-wants-to-use-your-confidential.html).

Comment: As a general suggestion for the future, if you have an issue that is easily reproducible, please change your system language to English before taking a screenshot. Sometimes words are lost in translation, and also it'll be easier for search engines to find solutions to the exact, original, English phrasing rather than a translation.

Comment: @interestinglythere you can change the system language on the fly? That's good to know! Will do.

Comment: There is one language setting for the entire system, but each app reads and applies the current language settings when it starts up, so you only need to relaunch an app to change its language.

STEPS:
1. Go to Language & Region preferences.
2. Make sure English is added and dragged to the top of the list.
3. Quit and relaunch any apps you want to appear in English.

Answer (score 4):

1. Open Keychain Access.app in your Applications > Utilities folder.
2. Highlight the login keychain on the left sidebar.
3. Select one of the sites you see the popup from the list of credentials and double-click to get the info panel.
4. On that panel select "Access Control".
5. Below "Always allow access by these applications" click on +, and navigate to Safari in your Applications folder. Save changes.
6. Close Keychain Access and restart Safari.

(adapted from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163531/70930). You may need to do steps 3-5 for each site for which that problem is occurring; I'm not certain.)

Answer (score -2):

### Solution A

1. In Finder, press the key 'option' and click on 'Library' under 'Go'.
2. In library folder, scroll down to 'keychain'.
3. Click on the arrow to the left of keychain to reveal what's under it.
4. Delete everything under keychain, but not the keychain folder itself.
5. (In my case, I had to delete 3-4 files and a folder).
6. Restart the mac.

### Solution B

Drag the window to the side of your screen and ignore it just like everybody else did to me

Comment: Removed your solution B because it basically deletes all data the user has. And if a backup is restored afterwards the keychain will be the same as before. Also for solution A, doesn't this delete all the keys the user has stored?

Comment: that's what happened to me before and i used that way to get rid of it